# Une limite fixée « à minuit » est-elle à la fin ou au début de la journée mentionnée?

Tags: usage, indications-de-temps, dates

Si on vous dit qu'un dossier est à rendre « avant le lundi 17 octobre à minuit »<sup>[1]</sup>, faut-il comprendre qu'il est à rendre le 16 octobre à 23 h 59, ou bien est-ce le 17 octobre à 23 h 59 ? Autremedit dit, dimanche soir ou lundi soir ?

---

<sup>[1] Oui, je vais passer un week-end studieux !</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Tel jour à minuit* signifie techniquement *le jour en question à 23:59:59.999*.
S'il faut rendre un dossier le 17 octobre à minuit, cela laisse donc toute la journée du 17 octobre pour ce faire <sup>(*)</sup>.

Un exemple : les impôts. [Le 30 mai à minuit](http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup;jsessionid=QBUZ12H5ZOZZRQFIEIPSFEY?typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_6232&temNvlPopUp=true) s'interprète comme expliqué plus haut, [comme le montre cet article publié le 30 mai](http://www.france-info.com/economie-finance-patrimoine-2011-05-30-declaration-de-revenus-dernier-delai-aujourd-hui-a-minuit-539916-22-24.html).

La formulation *tel jour à 0h00* serait plus ambiguë, mais je ne l'ai jamais rencontrée.

<sup>(*) Bon courage quand même :)</sup>

Comment: Certains jours vont jusque 23:59:60, voire 23:59:61 (mais ils sont encore plus rare).

Comment: :) Tout ce que l'on voudra pourvu que ça représente *fin_du_jour - epsilon*

Comment: @Joubarc - Tout de même pas rares au point d'exiger le singulier...

Comment: @Mouviciel grammaticalement, non, en effet — mais je crois me souvenir que, si c'est prévu, ça n'a encore jamais été appliqué.

Comment: @Joubarc: je pense que mouviciel parlait de ton "rare" sans "s" ;-)

Comment: @Nicolas qu'est-ce qui te fait croire que je n'avais pas compris ? (Et encore, je suis bien bon de ne pas essayer de prétendre que je l'avais fait exprès. Bon, ce ne serait pas très crédible, non plus.)

Comment: @Joubarc - C'est juste, cela n'a jamais été appliqué. [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconde_intercalaire) a son mot à dire sur le sujet.

Answer (score 9):

Pareil que [Shlublu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1460), le dossier est à rendre pour le 17 octobre à 23h59 au plus tard<sup>1</sup>.

J'ajouterais que la [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/minuit) de minuit abonde en ce sens également: minuit est l'« heure du milieu de la nuit, la douzième après midi, **la vingt-quatrième d'un jour.** »

Un autre exemple simple est celui de la messe de minuit du 24 décembre. Je gage que si quelqu'un se rend à l'église le 23 décembre à 23h59, il en trouvera la porte close.

<sup>1. Mais ce n'est pas une raison pour glandouiller sur french.se à la place de bosser.</sup>

Et pourtant…

Si la question posée était « à quel jour appartient 0h00 ? », les réponses penchent plus souvent dans l'autre sens ; voir par exemple sur [Yahoo! Questions/réponses](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090727144919AApoRDq) ou sur un autre [site quelconque](http://forum.phpfrance.com/php-deprecated/quel-jour-pour-0h00mn00s-t191.html).

Les [Décrets Relatifs à l'établissement de l'Ère Républicaine](http://www.gefrance.com/calrep/decrtxt.htm) semblent aller dans ce sens aussi:

> IV. La première année de la République française a commencé à minuit le 22 septembre 1792, et à (sic) fini à minuit, séparant le 21 du 22 septembre 1793.
> V. La deuxième année a commencé le 22 septembre 1793 à minuit, l'équinoxe vrai d'automne étant arrivé, pour l'observatoire de Paris, à 3 heures 7 minutes 19 secondes du soir.

Qui semble indiquer que « le 22 septembre 1793 à minuit » est le même moment que « minuit, séparant le 21 du 22 septembre 1793 », faute de quoi la journée du 22 septembre n'aurait appartenu ni à la première ni à la deuxième année.

J'ai déjà eu à traiter ce problème dans le cadre d'un club de loisirs vis-à-vis de la possibilité de passer une commande de matériel, et la solution simple consiste à ne pas utiliser minuit, mais plutôt 23h, par exemple. Bien entendu, dès qu'on parle d'une date limite, le problème se pose. Et il y a toujours des petits malins pour demander de quel fuseau horaire on parle.

De toutes façons, en tant qu'élève, si tu te demandes le 15 octobre si ton devoir est à rendre pour le 16 ou le 17 et que tu n'as jamais pensé à demander au prof de préciser… Disons que si tu invoques VDM, je cliquerai sur « tu l'as bien mérité ».